# How to get all info regarding the cell, based on cell_list.txt

Tags: regex, perl

In this case, I have two files, cell_list.txt and allcells.txt. In cell_list.txt were listed cell names that required. 
For example:

```
cell_abc
cell_acde
c_swer
```

Then, i have allcells.txt which show the details of all cells which more that 100 cells details. I found that the pattern seems to be quite same which all cell details starts with ***** and ends with 'END'. For example:

```
*****
Lib: lib_a
Cell: cell_abc
*****
info absw ...
info swea ...
END

*****
Lib: lib_a
Cell: cell_acdd
*****
info awee ...
info awod ...
info acwe ...
END

*****
Lib: lib_b
Cell: cell_acde
*****
info wseo ...
info poee ...
info awec ...
END

*****
Lib: lib_b
Cell: c_swer
*****
info rtoe ...
info swkt ...
END
```

I need to get all the details based on cell listed in cell_list.txt and somehow copy to a new file for each cell, cellname.txt. Is there any way to make this works using csh or perl? Expected output as below.

Content of cell_abc.txt:

```
*****
Lib: lib_a
Cell: cell_abc
*****
info absw ...
info swea ...
END
```

Content of cell_acde.txt:

```
*****
Lib: lib_b
Cell: cell_acde
*****
info wseo ...
info poee ...
info awec ...
END
```

Content of c_swer.txt:

```
*****
Lib: lib_b
Cell: c_swer
*****
info rtoe ...
info swkt ...
END
```

This is roughly on what i have on my script now as i am not familiar with perl.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl     
use strict;
use warnings;

my $file = 'allcells.txt';
my $list = 'cell_list.txt';
my $string;
my @matches = $file =~ m/(^\* .+? END)/g;
{
  local $/=undef;
  open FILE, $file or die "Couldn't open file: $!";
  $string = <FILE>;
  close FILE;

        while(<>){
        if ($string = @matches) #how to check on cell_list.txt if the cell is listed in the file or not before checking the matching string.
        {
                print $string; #how to extract and print the matching string to new file which will be named based on the cell name listed in cell_list.txt
        }
       }
}
```

Comment: This is pretty straight forward in perl.  Read the file in as a long string.  Search for `*** ... *** ... END` blocks using a regular expression.  For each block, save it to a file.  If the file is huge or doesn't fit easily into memory, you can build up your blocks line-by-line and then save them when you  hit the END keyword.  What code have you tried?

Comment: I just started by reading the file as long string using  'local $/=undef;' but then i am not familiar on how to find matching block using the regular expression.

Comment: `my @matches = $txt =~ m|(some string .+? some other string)|g`  have a read of https://perldoc.perl.org/perlretut.html

Answer (score 1):

You need to actually read in the file first, instead of trying to perform a regex match on an empty string.  Iterate over the other file to populate a hash, and use hash membership to decide whether to print out a section into a new file.  You can use `\Q` and `\E` inside the regex to make a literal match.  The trailing `/s` regex flag treats the string like one long line.

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my $file = 'allcells.txt';
my $list = 'cell_list.txt';

my %required_cells;
open my $fhrc, "<$list"
    or die "Unable to open '$list' : $!";
while ( my $line = <$fhrc> ) {
    chomp($line);
    $required_cells{ $line } = 1;
}

open my $fh, "<$file"
    or die "Unable to open '$file' : $!";
my $allcells_txt = do { local $/; <$fh> }; # Slurp file into a string

my @matches = $allcells_txt =~ m|\Q*****\E.+?\Q*****\E.+?END|gs;
for my $group (@matches) {
    my ($cell) = $group =~ m|Cell: (\w+)|s;
    if ( exists $required_cells{ $cell } ) {
        print "Cell [ $cell ] is required\n";
        my $out_name = "$cell.txt";
        open my $out, ">$out_name"
            or die "Unable to open '$out_name' for writing : $!";
        print $out "$group . "\n";
        close $out
            or die "Unable to close '$out_name' : $!";
        print "==> Created $out_name\n";
    } else {
        print "Skipping $cell\n";
    }
}
```

**output**

```
Cell [ cell_abc ] is required
==> Created cell_abc.txt
Skipping cell_acdd
Cell [ cell_acde ] is required
==> Created cell_acde.txt
Cell [ c_swer ] is required
==> Created c_swer.txt
```

Comment: Hi, i did try the solution you gave, however, errors occured in line 23:     if ( exists $required_cells{ $cell } ) . The errors shown: Use of uninitialized value in exists at test.pl line 23, <$fh> line 1.
Use of uninitialized value in concatenation (.) or string at test.pl line 23, <$fh> line 1.
Cell [  ] is required
Use of uninitialized value in concatenation (.) or string at test.pl line 23, <$fh> line 1.
==> Created .txt

Comment: Looks like `$cell` didn't get set.  Print out $group and see what it should be, probably the `\w+` ( match word characters ) failed, you may need to adjust the regular expression to something else.  Add `defined $cell or die $group;` before the `if` expression.